# Using third party library data not come in proper json form

Tags: ios, swift

i am new in iOS developer . and i just want to ask that when i attached third party library Alamofire using get method the data is coming but not in proper Json form,the key value comes null of each identity..please 
help me here is my code:

```
 let headers = ["Authorization":"","Accept": "application/json"]
 Alamofire.request(.GET,requestString,headers:headers,encoding: .JSON)
            .responseJSON { response in
                print(response)
                print(response.request)
```

Comment: please provide me sample

Comment: Look at `response.result.value` and cast it to the appropriate type. If simple dictionary, then `if let dictionary = response.result.value as? [String: AnyObject] { ... }`. Or if an array of dictionaries, `if let dictionaries = response.result.value as? [[String: AnyObject]] { ... }`. Etc.

Comment: print(response.result.value)  when i use this command the data comes in  {
        addresses =         (
        );
        apiKey = "66f36acb-8ec7-4945-9d64-d34557b1efa3";
        baseCountry = "<null>";
        baseCurrency = "<null>";
        baseTimezone = "<null>";
        contactTypes =

Comment: why the data not comes in = instead of : and in array it shows by () this is problem or by default it show like this

Comment: It's because the data _did_ come in as JSON (with colons, etc.), but `responseJSON` has already converted this raw JSON payload into an array of dictionary objects. So, you're seeing the Swift representation of these nested array and dictionary objects, not the raw JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, url, parameters: parameter as? [String : AnyObject]).responseJSON { (response: Response<AnyObject, NSError>) in
    if error == nil {
        print(response.result.value)
    }
}
```

Comment: In get method why we need parameters??

Comment: if you want to pass some data then you can just pass it as nsdictionary and just the base url and it will render them and send them like ? and & in it. its just for simplifying the way of requesting

Comment: you can do without it but i think you should not concat the key and values when Alamofire is doing it itself.

Comment: No i did not pass any data..i just need to get only

Comment: then just pass blank. I was using that for universal requests so i just managed that way. You can pass just [:] in that

Comment: sir can you please tell me why we taking string:anyobject

Comment: its the acceptable format for that function of Alamofire. thats why.

Answer (score 0):

When you call `responseJSON`, it parses the JSON for you. So, if the JSON was an array of dictionaries (as shown by one of your other questions), then the `response.result.value` would not contain that raw JSON, but rather a nested structure of arrays and dictionaries. You can retrieve this data by unwrapping it (e.g. with `if let` or `guard let`):

```
Alamofire.request(requestString, headers: headers)
    .responseJSON { response in
        guard let dictionaries = response.result.value as? [[String: AnyObject]] else {
            print(response.result.error)
            return
        }

        // do something with the array of dictionaries, e.g. to show the names

        for dictionary in dictionaries {
            if let name = dictionary["name"] as? String {
                print(name)
            } else {
                print("Name not found")
            }
        }
}
```